Flutter app returns a different public IP when making a get request https://api.ipify.org
Steps:

Load https://api.ipify.org on android chrome browser.
This returns an public IP address 152.58.XX.XX
Now load the same URL within the Flutter app using HttpClient from dart.io or by using the http package.
This returns an public IP address 152.58.YY.YY
Shouldn't it also the return the same public IP.
Note: This only happens on Jio Network.

We are expecting same IP on both flutter app and browser.
Some tests:

On Airtel mobile network both returns same public IP address.
On Jio mobile network both returns different public IP address.
I build native android app [kotlin] with okHttp and did the same flow. This works as expected on both Airtel and Jio
I build a flutter package that wraps the kotlin okHttp implementation. This works as expected on both Airtel and Jio.

Why do we see different IP only when using flutter http client with jio.
Sample Code to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/subinsv/flutter_ip_issue
Result on JIO Mobile Network:
Top section is flutter app, bottom section is browser


I tried with your website and it is returning same string both in flutter(android) app using http latest version and android chrome browser when using Jio. I can't see the abnormal behavior as you said.
It could be better if you can give the reproducible code with environment settings.

Thanks @Ultranmus.
That is weird. I will try to create a code sample that can reproduce this issue.

Have you tried on different device. It can possible the issue might be with a particular device with Jio Network

@Ultranmus, yes we tried on multiple devices. All yields same results.
Updated original question with link to repo and screenshots -> https://github.com/subinsv/flutter_ip_issue

i cloned your repo, tested it on real android device and emulator in Jio network. The result was same. See this screenshot
The only difference in b/w my version and your is you uses 3.3.3 dart sdk but mine is 3.3.1 version. So i have to downgrade the dart sdk version in both the app pubspec.yml file and the http_client package pubspec.yml file to 3.3.1. Can you try to downgrade it and check.

Thanks @Ultranmus for testing it out.
I will downgrade and give it a try.

@Ultranmus I tried with dart 3.3.1, flutter 3.19.3.
Still can reproduce it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The issue is caused by how Dart handles the Ipv4 and Ipv6 connection network connection.
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/55405#issuecomment-2068876528
